# label in enumerate, want to reference section

Tags: cross-referencing, enumerate

Let's say we are in chapter 3, section 2

```
\begin{enumerate}
      \item abc \label{sec:L1}
      \item bcd
 \end{enumerate}

 \ref{sec:L1}
```

This will now do reference '(1)' because it's item 1. Can I change something, so the reference says (3.2)?

Comment: Isn't it easier to set the label just after the relevant `\section` command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can using [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem)'s personalized `ref` key:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{2}% Just for this example
\chapter{A chapter}
\setcounter{section}{1}% Just for this example
\section{A section}
\begin{enumerate}[ref=(\thesection)]
  \item abc \label{sec:L1}
  \item bcd
\end{enumerate}

See Section~\ref{sec:L1}.

\end{document}
```

However, you will lose the capability to `\label`-and-`\ref` the individual `\item`s (unless you do some extra work).

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you want?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{cleveref} 

\begin{document}

\section{Test section}

See \cref{item1,item3}. 

\begin{enumerate}[ref =\thesection.\theenumi]
\item A first item. \label{item1}

\item A second item \label{item2}. 

\item Last item. \label{item3}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, but not quite. I clarified the question.

Comment: @Martin Čejke: I don't understand: if you want to reference the section, you just have to put the label just after `\section{section title}`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Thank you, maybe this doesn't answer the OP's question, but this was exactly what I was looking after.